# Convert timedelta column in minuts

Tags: python

Im trying to covert one columne in format timedelta in minutes im serching in web and i know that i need to use first total.seconds() but i can do it whith column:

```
Orden['Tiempo_xx_entre']=Orden['Lag_fecha_hora']-Orden['FECHA_HORA']
Orden['sec']= Orden['Tiempo_xx_entre'].total_seconds()
```

But the mistake with this are:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'
```

can u help me to convert the column Tiempo_xx_entre in minutes?

Comment: Add the definition of `Series` to your code. From the error message, this is not a problem about conversion but about class members definition.

Answer (score 0):

I use dt to solve like this:

```
Orden['Tiempo_xx_entre']=((Orden['FECHA_HORA']Orden['Lag_fecha_hora']).dt.total_seconds())/ 60
```